# Why Doesn't Javascript DOM 2 "Click" Event Work

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My question is, Why doesn't the click event work when other events do work using the same code? Consider the following code examples from http://www.pricelearman.com/__dev (2 underscores)

**For Square 2 using "click" event**

```
function showWorkPane() {
    var _workID = document.getElementById("workID");
    _workID.addEventListener("click", showWorkPaneHandler, false);
}

function showWorkPaneHandler(e) {
    var _workPane = document.getElementById("workPane");
    e.preventDefault();
   _workPane.style.display = "block";   
}
```

**Clicking on the link "Work" does not show the `workPane`.**

**For Square 3 using `mouseover` event**

```
function showAboutPane() {
    var aboutID = document.getElementById("aboutID");
    aboutID.addEventListener("mouseover", showAboutPaneHandler, false);
}

function showAboutPaneHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var v = document.getElementById("aboutPane");
    v.style.display = "block";
}
```

**Rolling-Over the link "ABOUT" shows the aboutPane hover effect as expected**

**For Square 4 using "mousedown" event**

```
function showConnectPane() {
    var connectID = document.getElementById("connectID");
    connectID.addEventListener("mousedown", showConnectPaneHandler, false);
}

function showConnectPaneHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var v = document.getElementById("connectPane");
    v.style.display = "block";
}
```

**Holding mouse down on the link "CONNECT" shows the `connectPane` as expected**

What am I missing about the click event. It's counter-intuitive to me that it would not follow the same pattern as the other mouse events.

I'm trying to preclude interference from the link's default action by using `e.preventDefault();`.

I know a click event is a sequence of simple events: `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `click`.

Is there something blocking this sequence?

The full code can be reviewed at http://www.pricelearman.com/__dev (2 underscores). The code may not be optimum, but it is functionally correct – binding is accomplished and functions are called, etc – else the above code would not be working at all.

Thanks for your time and expertise. This is a vexing question to me. It seems so fundamental and simple. I'm new to JavaScript and I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For Square 2 using "click" event
>
> ```
> function showWorkPane() {
>     var _workID = document.getElementById("workID");
>     _workID.addEventListener("click", showWorkPaneHandler, false);
> }
>
> function showWorkPaneHandler(e) {
>     var _workPane = document.getElementById("workPane");
>     e.preventDefault();
>    _workPane.style.display = "block";   
> }
> ```
>
> Clicking on the link "Work" does not show the workPane.

Well what I currently can find at http://www.pricelearman.com/__dev/_js/main.js is

```
// Show work navigation
function showWorkPane() {
    var workID = document.getElementById("workID");
    workID.addEventListener("mouseover", showWorkPaneHandler, false);
//                           ^^^^^^^^^
}

function showWorkPaneHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var v = document.getElementById("workPane");
    v.style.display = "block";
}
```

Looks quite obvious to me why `click` events show no effect. There are none bound.

Comment: My understanding of DOM 2 events is that the element.addEventListener("event", function, phase) is all that is required for binding. It certainly works for "mouseover" & "mousedown" so why not for "click".

Comment: It would work for `click` as well, you only would need to try… your script does not contain the string `click` at all.

Comment: You are essentially correct. The online version of main.js had not been updated. I put up the current version and "click" worked. Unfortunately, my "click outside" jQuery didn't. So, on to the next problem. Thanks for your input. It helped a lot.